# Unhiding and Hiding columns within my workbook

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Is their anyway to hide data in an excel workbook if the data is not their?
For instance say I use

```
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx)
```

The Dataframe that it produces has a table in it which has columns that are already made for January through December Since I only have data so far for January and February I only want those columns to show. The reason for this is because March to December there is no data yet so the columns come up blank. I want to basically hide columns unless their is data in them and when data does become present in those columns I want it to unhide and show the data for that month.

Comment: What Python library are you using to manipulate excel data? Have you checked it's documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write to Excel file:

```
df.to_excel('yourfile.xlsx',index=False)
```

Open using `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('YourSheetName')
```

For each column check if cell in second row has a value and set column as hidden if not:

```
for col in ws.columns:
  if not col[2].value:
    ws.column_dimensions[col[2].column].hidden = True
```

Save to Excel file:

```
wb.save('yourfile_modified.xlsx')
```

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!